# POSTing xml over HTTPS with Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, https

This is going to be running on a server which will then send the xml request to another server (over which I have no control). I can't afford to write an xml to the hard drive for every request. So ideally I'd like to create an xml without creating the file.

This shows how to send an xml file (not an object) over https: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iisinfsv/v9r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.iis.ia.restapi.doc%2Ftopics%2Fr_restapi_sending_https_java.html I've got that part working, problem is even after changing the content type to xml I think it was simply sending the content of the xml as plain text which seems very inelegant.

I'd rather avoid third party jars as much as possible but I do have access to the apache.axiom and axis 2 library.

So long story short: how do I make an xml object and then send it via HTTPS to a third party web-service that is not using SOAP or REST.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP request is generally correct to send XML as text, with the correct content type.

If you have a DOM object of some sort, you would just serialize it to XML, as text, either on disk or in a buffer or a string, and then send that, as per the link, to the other server. The other server will parse the XML string and get whatever form of object it wants.